# How can I create a requirements.txt in Google colab?

Tags: python, package, google-colaboratory, python-import, requirements

I have already tested the following:

!pip freeze > requirements.txt --> saves all packages in the environment

pipreqs --> returns an empty file

I need a compilation of all **imported packages** with the corresponding version. How can I do this in Google Colab without getting all installed packages?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I had similar issue when using

```
!pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

you get all the packages initially installed in colab.

You can try to install session_info at the beginning:

```
!pip install session-info
```

Then imports all you need and run this to see what was imported:

```
import session_info
session_info.show()
```

Update:

This command might give you a glimpse but it doesn't seem very complete. I quickly went back to the old way, added the dependency in a local python project and used one of these 2:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: Just works for me, ```!pip install session-info
import session_info
session_info.show()
!pipreqs```

Comment: @baponkar I was trying to reproduce your solution, but I don't know how to connect the output of `session_info.show()` with `!pipreqs`. Thanks

Comment: I found it: `session_info.show(write_req_file=True, req_file_name='requirements.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all imported modules by doing:

```
import sys
print(sys.modules.keys())
```